# Retrogit result

Tags: java, android, retrofit, callback

Добрый день почему мой метод возвращает NULL?

```
public class NameWarehouse {
    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";


    public String result;



    public String GetNameWarehouse (String guid){

        ServisAPI api = RetrofitClient.getApiService();
        Call<CatalogWarehouses> call = api.getWarehouses(guid);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CatalogWarehouses>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CatalogWarehouses> call, Response<CatalogWarehouses> response) {

               // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Call " +call);


                // amountValue = response.body();
                String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(response.body());
                JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
                try {
                    dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                    result = (String) dataJsonObj.get("Description");
                    //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Call " + result);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CatalogWarehouses> call, Throwable t) {

            }

        });
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Result " + result);
        return result;


    }


}
```

Comment: Потому что возврат значения синхронный, а запрос в сеть асинхронный.

Comment: Тогда как мне реализовать задуманное?

Comment: Например, определите колбек `Callback<CatalogWarehouses>()` там, где вам нужен результат и передайте его в ваш класс с запросом.